# Test class not executing scope

Tags: community, batch, salesforce-id

I am implementing a batch to delete few records.
I am querying in the starting for records to be deleted and deleted the whole scope like this,

```
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext info, List<OpportunityLineItem> scope){
        //Delete the whole scope as requested from the VF Page.
        if(!Scope.isEmpty()){
            try{
                Delete scope;
            }Catch(exception e){
                errMsgs.add(e);  
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is when I execute the test class for this, I don't see the execute method covered in batch even though assertion is passed.
It is giving me the expected result.

When I change the asset statement to some other value, it fails as it is wrong.

But the execution is covered from test class.

Am I missing anything here..?

Comment: If the whole execute method is not covered then may be you don't have any records inserted in your test context.

Comment: You also need to have Test.stopTest() to make sure the async work is completed. Suggest you post your test code as your description of the problem is a little hard to follow.